# Deriving a new list of lists from two other lists, where the elements from L1 are appended if they're not in L2

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've been studying for an upcoming test and while practicing I found this script; which is supposed to return a new list of lists containing the lists from `L1` that do not contain any string from `L2`:

What I have done is to compare each element from `L2` with the elements from `L1`, and add them to `listas` without any duplicates. The part where I'm stuck is right after my loop finishes to run, I get a list of lists but without any actual comparison. I've tried to use a second list and it works but if `len(L2) > 2` it wouldn't work, also `.remove()` but sometimes the element to remove is not in the list yet and I get some errors.

```
from typing import List
def non_intersecting(L1: List[List[str]], L2: List[str]) -> List[List[str]]:    
"""Return a new list that contains the original lists inside L1 that do not
contain any of the string in L2

>>> non_intersecting([['e', 'h', 'c', 'w'], ['p', 'j'], ['w', 's', 'u']], ['k', 'w'])
[['p', 'j']]
"""

listas = []

if len(L2) == 0:
    return L1
elif len(L2) > 0:
    for index in range(len(L2)):
        for lists in L1:
            if lists not in listas:
                if L2[index] not in lists:
                    listas.append(lists)

return listas
```

Any help? Would be great to do it without any modules nor `zip`,`lambdas`, as I'm not looking to submit this but rather understand the basics before my test.

Comment: Here are three different ways, using increasingly more advanced constructs: https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/0aa9f0bd539a8863479e8f90fc8fa530

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nice man, I used the first method; I didn't use `zip` though, but works the same. Would you say that I can avoid using `break` in that script?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with regards to `zip`, I didn't use it either. But yeah, you can leave out the break but then it won't be short-circuiting. Essentially, that loop with the boolean flag re-implements `any`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh sorry I meant `set`, alright then

Comment: Well, you really should be using a set. You can just use `L2` directly, but list-membership tests are expensive. If you expect L2 to be large, then it is definitely worth the conversion

Answer (score 1):

```
def non_intersecting(l1, l2):
    out = []
    for sub_list in l1:
        if len(list(set(sub_list).intersection(l2))) == 0:  #no common strings
            out.append(sub_list)
    return out
```

For this simple operation no need to add List() constructors..

Comment: This is really inefficient: `len(list(set(sub_list).intersection(l2))) == 0:` and there is no need for the `len(list(...)) == 0`, `set` objects already have a length, and anyway, you can just just `if not set(sub_list).intersection(l2)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def non_intersecting(L1, L2):
    s2 = set(L2)
    lists_sets = ((l, set(l)) for l in L1)
    return [l for l, s in lists_sets if not s & s2]
```

Answer (score 1):

For checking membership, you can use `any()` or `not any()`

```
x=[['e', 'h', 'c', 'w'], ['p', 'j'], ['w', 's', 'u']]
y=['k', 'w']

def non_intersecting(l1, l2):
    outlist=[]
    for sublist in x:
        if not any([elem in sublist for elem in y]):
            outlist.append(sublist)
    return outlist

non_intersecting(x, y)

[['p', 'j']]
```

The above can also be reduced to a list comprehension

```
def non_intersecting(l1, l2):
    return [i for i in x if not any([j in i for j in y])]
```

Comment: `x` and `y` are not declared.